# How to get data attribute of option tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Want to get data attribute value from selected dropdown option.

```
<select name="selection" id="mySelect">
    <option value="21" data-rc="25" data-clnc="10">Treatment</option>
</select>

var rc = ? //value of data-rc
var clnc = ? //value of data-clnc
```

No jQuery please only JavaScript :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can read them out via [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

```js
var option = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[0];

console.log(option.dataset.rc)
console.log(option.dataset.clnc)
```

```html
<option value="21" data-rc="25" data-clnc="10">Treatment</option>
```

Or, if you want to get the values of the selected option:

```js
var selection = document.getElementById("mySelect");

selection.onchange = function(event){
  var rc = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.rc;
  var clnc = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.clnc;
  console.log("rc: " + rc);
  console.log("clnc: " + clnc);
};
```

```html
<select name="selection" id="mySelect">
<option value="21" data-rc="25" data-clnc="10">Treatment</option>
<option value="21" data-rc="23" data-clnc="30">Treatment1</option>
<option value="21" data-rc="31" data-clnc="50">Treatment2</option>
<option value="21" data-rc="14" data-clnc="75">Treatment3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Index is not always 0 :(

Comment: If you want to get the values of the selected option, I edited the answer. If you want to get *all* the values, you'll have to iterate. Anyway, now you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks, I forget the options property of the target. Nowadays I tend to be reluctant to dig deeper into HTML elements/nodes with their properties/methods. I prefer using dataset, instead of getAtttibute, although dataset may not work in some browsers.

Comment: Your answer gave me a great idea how to fix a similar problem I was having :D cheers

Answer (score 20):

suppose we have a select field

```
    <select id="ddlViewBy">
      <option value="1" data-rc="25" data-clnc="10" selected="selected">test1</option>
      <option value="2" >test2</option>
      <option value="3">test3</option>
    </select>
```

Now we will get the select list and its selected option

```
    var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
    var option= e.options[e.selectedIndex];
```

Now we have the selected option we can get its attribtues

```
    var attrs = option.attributes;
```

attrs is the attributes array you can get attribtues by index you want.

Or you can get attribtues by

```
    var datarc = option.getAttribute("data-rc");
```

Comment: Good. This is the alternative way for working with data attributes. The other one is using dataset, which I prefer, although may not work in some browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Check this working pen

[working pen](http://codepen.io/ritesh14887/pen/WxzPEj)

```
$('#options').on('change', function(){
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-rc'))
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-clnc'))
});
```

Comment: No jQuery please only JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var mySelect = document.querySelector('#mySelect')
        console.log('mySelect value ' + mySelect.value)
        console.log('mySelect data-rc ' + mySelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-rc"))
        console.log('mySelect data-clnc ' + mySelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-clnc"))
```

```html
<select name="selection" id="mySelect">
    <option value="21" data-rc="25" data-clnc="10">Treatment</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

$(selector).find("option:selected").data("rc") for rc and clnc for clnc where selector is your "select" tag id/class

Comment: No jQuery please only JavaScript

Comment: No jQuery. Instead, use DOM API, from which we can use either dataset property or getAttribute method of the corresponding DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody looking for the simplest answer, here is the solution.

Javascript:

```
function getURL()
{
    var link = $("#title :selected").data('link');
    console.log(link);
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="title" onchange="getURL()">
    <option data-link="https://www.google.com" value="1">Single</option>
    <option data-link="https://www.google.com/search" value="2">Double</option>
</select>
```

Happy Programming!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with jquery selector

```
var rc = $('select option:selected').data('rc');
```

Comment: No, it's said above that no jQuery. There are 2 correct answers that other guys had given : one using dataset, the other using getAttribute. All use plain DOM API, no jQuery involved.