# Html element get specific attribute value

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get the "data-price" attribute from the option element onChange. getting the value does work, but i can not get the data-price attribute. I have the following code, which doesnt work.

```js
function getComboA(selectObject) {
  var printit = selectObject.getAttribute("data-price");  
  console.log(printit);
}
/*with this it gets the value tho, but i need the data-price attribute
function getComboA(selectObject) {
  var printit = selectObject.value;  
  console.log(printit);
}

*/
```

```html
<select id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
      <option  value="">Select combo</option>
      <option data-price=100 value="Value1">Text1</option>
      <option data-price=200 value="Value2">Text2</option>
      <option data-price=2003 value="Value3">Text3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data attribute of option tag in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519791/how-to-get-data-attribute-of-option-tag-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By **JavaScript** :

```
var selection = document.getElementById("comboA");
selection.onchange = function(event){
  var printit  = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.price;
  console.log(printit);
};
```

Or **JQuery** :

```js
$('#comboA').change(function(){
      var printit =$(this).find(':selected').attr('data-price')
      console.log(printit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="comboA" >
      <option  value="">Select combo</option>
      <option data-price=100 value="Value1">Text1</option>
      <option data-price=200 value="Value2">Text2</option>
      <option data-price=2003 value="Value3">Text3</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should make it work:

```
const comboA = document.querySelector('#comboA');
comboA.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.price);
});
```

With this you can also omit the function call in html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `selectedIndex` of the `selectObject` to get the index which you can use to get the selected option and then you can get the `data-price` attribute of that option.
Code:

```
function getComboA(selectObject) {
  var selectedIndex = selectObject.selectedIndex;  
  var selectedPrice = selectObject[selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price");
  console.log(selectedPrice);
}
```